# Iterate over ID column, creating a new graph for each unique ID

Tags: r, networking, igraph

Imagine I have the following data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="TrxID Items Quant Team_Id
Trx1 A 3 11
Trx1 B 1 11
Trx1 C 1 12
Trx2 E 3 13
Trx2 B 1 13
Trx3 B 1 14
Trx3 C 4 14
Trx4 D 1 15
Trx4 E 1 15
Trx4 A 1 15
Trx5 F 5 18
Trx5 B 3 13
Trx5 C 2 19
Trx5 D 1 20", header=T)

dat[1, ]$Team_Id <- paste0(c('11','19'), collapse = ',')
dat[6, ]$Team_Id <- paste0(c('14','13'), collapse = ',')
```

Some people are on more than one team, so they have multiple team_ids stored in a list.  I can generate an adjacency matrix of all the occurrences, and turn it into a graph to perform network analysis like so:

```
tabbed <- xtabs(~ TrxID + Items, data=dat, sparse = TRUE)
co_occur <- crossprod(tabbed, tabbed)
diag(co_occur) <- 0
co_occur

g <- graph.adjacency(co_occur, weighted=TRUE, mode ='undirected')
g <- simplify(g)
```

However, what I want to do is to group by the `team_id` column, and to generate the above adjacency matrix and graph objects for every unique team_id.  I tried using a for loop to achieve this, but I don't believe it is feasible given the size of my dataset. Moreover, it cannot handle the cases when people are on more than one team (as it would require another for loop to iterate over each element in a list).

For example,

```
complete_teams <- data.frame(team_id = c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20))

for(i in complete_teams$team_id){
  if(i %in% dat$Team_Id) {
        newdata = subset(dat, Team_Id == i)
        tabbed <- xtabs(~ TrxID + Items, data=newdata, sparse = TRUE)
        co_occur <- crossprod(tabbed, tabbed)
        diag(co_occur) <- 0
        print(co_occur)
        g <- graph.adjacency(co_occur, weighted=TRUE, mode ='undirected')
        g <- simplify(g)


  }

}
```

So, what I'm wondering is

1. what is the best way to generate separate networks for each `team_id`?
2. how should the resultant graph objects for each `team_id` be stored in order to do analysis on them later?

If there is a more obvious way of doing this within the network analysis paradigm, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a way to do it using `by`. But I am preprocessing the data before to split the comma seprated column.

```
create_g <- function(dx){
  tabbed <- xtabs(~ TrxID + Items, data=dx, sparse = TRUE)
  co_occur <- crossprod(tabbed, tabbed)
  diag(co_occur) <- 0
  g <- graph.adjacency(co_occur, weighted=TRUE, mode ='undirected')
  g <- simplify(g)
  g
}
```

I am using `data.table` to split the column since it is by group of ID:

```
library(data.table)
out <- setDT(dat)[, {
  data.table(new_id = unlist(strsplit(Team_Id,",")),
  .SD)
   },Team_Id]
```

We can no more use the data.table framework to apply `created_g` since the result is not a nested list:

```
by(out,out$new_id,FUN=create_g)
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but does this deal with the issue that some people have team_ids that are lists, rather than single numbers?

Comment: You're right. I update the solution to pre processes the data.

Comment: Thanks so much!  How would you recommend storing each of the values generated via the `by` function? Inside rows of a dataframe?